# Identity Role-based Authorization is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a custom implementation of the ASP.NET Identity base, using Dapper instead of Entity Framework largely from the tutorial here: http://blog.markjohnson.io/exorcising-entity-framework-from-asp-net-identity/.

Everything is fine with signing users in and out with my AuthenticationManager. However, as soon as I redirect anywhere after logging the user in, the httpcontext is basically null and the user is no longer authenticated. If I use the [Authorize] attribute as well, then the user is automatically declared as Unauthorized, throwing a 401 error.

Here are parts of my AccountController:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(Login login, string redundant)
{
    var master = new MasterModel();
    if (ModelState.IsValid && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(login.Email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(login.PasswordHash)))
    {
        var user = await Models.User.FetchUserByEmail(login.Email);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, true); 
            master.User = user; // User is now signed in - No problem
            return RedirectToAction("Overview", "Account", master);
        }
    }
    TempData["Message"] = "Your username or password was not recognised. Please try again.";
    return View(master);
}

[HttpGet]
//[Authorize(Roles = "admin,subscriber")] // 403 when uncommented
public ActionResult Overview(MasterModel master = null)
{
    // master is just a blank new MasterModel ??
    if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // User is always null/blank identity
        TempData["Message"] = "Please log in to view this content";
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", master);
    }

    var userName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name)
        ? TempData["UserName"].ToString()
        : HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

    var user = Models.User.FetchUserByEmail(userName).Result;

    if (master == null) master = new MasterModel();
    master.User = user;

    return View(master);
}
```

My UserStore implements the following interfaces:

```
public class UserStore : IUserStore<User>, IUserPasswordStore<User>, IUserSecurityStampStore<User>, IQueryableUserStore<User>, IUserRoleStore<User>
```

My RoleStore just implements `IQueryableRoleStore<Role>`

User and Role simply implement `IUser` and `IRole` respectively

What am I missing?

**Update1:** 
Here's part of the AuthenticatonManager:

```
public IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    }
}

private async Task SignInAsync(User user, bool isPersistent)
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
}
```

Comment: Have you set up the app to use the cookie authentication?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Yep. I've updated the question with the current AuthenticationManager and the SignInAsync() method that gets called. For reference, the SignIn is successful as far as I can see.

Comment: I mean the `UseCookieAuthentication` called on `IAppBuilder`. The `SignIn` possibly just doesn't create a cookie. You can easily verify it with an http debugger like Fiddler.

Comment: That's what I missed! Didn't set it up in the IAppBuilder! Thank you @WiktorZychla

Comment: Next time if someone helps you in a comment, mention that and let this person answer and accept this answer. Part of the SO fun is not only getting help from others but also scoring points for helping others :)

Comment: @WiktorZychla Whoops, Sorry Wiktor, I got all excited and wanted to share the solution with the world :) I've not marked mine as the answer yet, so if you want the points, feel free to add your solution and I'll mark yours as the solution.

Comment: No problem, just remember this for next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @WiktorZychla for pointing out the answer.

Turns out I was missing a fundamental step of adding the cookie authentication to IAppBuilder.

Here's how the OwinStartup.cs now looks for reference:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(appNamespace.OwinStartup))]

namespace appNamespace
{
    public class OwinStartup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will save someone else from tearing their hair out!